# Clarification on MySQL innodb_flush_method variable

Tags: mysql, innodb

Let me begin by admitting that I'm very ignorant of the inner workings of hard disks. So when I read over the manual for the variable [innodb_flush_method](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method), it confused me. Can I get an explanation in layman's terms on the difference in O_DSYNC and O_DIRECT, and how to know if it's a performance issue on a database server.

Some stats on my setup: Mac OSX 10.6 (32-bit kernel, since architecture is out of date) running MySQL 5.1.49-64bit (hoping it would allow me to use the memory). 8GB RAM, ~6GB of innodb data/indexes.

Comment: I don't know if Mac OS X supports a proper direct IO option - I did not think it did.  You're the second person I've seen *today* get confused by that manual page.  I have an open bug on it here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54306

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an explanation on how `fdatasync()` works vs how `fsync()` works

`fdatasync()` flushes all data buffers of a file to disk (before the system call returns). It resembles `fsync()` but is not required to update the metadata, such as access time. Applications that access databases or log files often write a tiny data fragment (e.g., one line in a log file) and then call `fsync()` immediately in order to ensure that the written data is physically stored on the harddisk. Unfortunately, `fsync()` will always initiate two write operations

- one write operation for the newly written data
- one write operation in order to update the modification time stored in the [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)

If the modification time is not a part of the transaction concept, then `fdatasync()` can be used to avoid unnecessary [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) disk write operations.

In English, `O_DSYNC` is faster than `O_DIRECT` since `O_DIRECT` calls `fsync()` twice (one for logs and one for data) and `fsync()` verifies data writes via two write operations. Using `O_DSYNC` calls `fdatasync()` and `fsync()`. You can think of `fdatasync()` as doing an asynchronous `fsync()` (not verifying data).

Looking at the numbers, `O_DSYNC` does four write ops, two of which are verified, while `fsync()` does four write operations, all being verified afterwards.

## CONCLUSION

### `O_DSYNC`

- faster than `O_DIRECT`
- Data may/may not be consistent due to latency or an outright crash

### `O_DIRECT`

- more stable
- data consistent
- naturally slower

I hope this answer helps, and I hope I didn't make things worse for you.

Comment: Worth pointing out: O_DIRECT is only used on the table-space files, not on the logs.  Also - whether O_DIRECT is going to be useful or not depends on the hardware.  I linked to an open documentation bug as a comment to the author's question.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, Morgan. I'll correct this.

Comment: O_DSYNC is synchronous write, how can you conclude that it is faster that asynchronous + fsync?

Comment: @noonex fdatasync() is synchronous for its data, not its metadata. According to http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=23618&seqNum=5, `This means that in principal, fdatasync can execute faster than fsync because it needs to force only one disk write instead of two. However, in current versions of Linux, these two system calls actually do the same thing, both updating the file's modification time.` At the time I wrote my post 3.5 yrs ago, it was true, especially with older versions of Linux.

Comment: @noonex According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sync_(Unix), `The related system call fsync() commits just the buffered data relating to a specified file descriptor. fdatasync() is also available to write out just the changes made to the data in the file, and not necessarily the file's related metadata.` (That Wiki was last updated July 28, 2014).

Comment: I reference mainly to log writes from this part of manual "uses O_SYNC to open and flush the log files". That should mean that all writes to log are synchronous. And log writes is the thing which limits performace in short run (data writes may be delayed for long time and merged/optimized/etc)