# Where should I look for my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I want to add `innodb_file_per_table` statement to `my.cnf` file.

Where is `my.cnf`?

Could I change this file when I have an online site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you add it to my.cnf (wherever it is), make sure you add it as follows:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table
```

A mysql restart is required to implement this for all new InnoDB tables. Doing this does not make all the InnoDB tables jump out of ibdata1.

[*You can cleanup InnoDB so that all tables and their indexes reside in separate tablespace files*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261).

You will also need to [**tune the InnoDB parameters**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/optimizing-innodb-default-settings/4325#4325).

There needs to be some downtime to do this cleanup. Once done, you never have to go about doing it again.

For now, if you want to do it to a live site, you must run this:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table = 1;
```

Comment: tnx, how should I add _innodb_file_per_table_ on a live site?

Comment: You can add innodb_file_per_table anytime to my.cnf once you find or create it for the first time. Otherwise, if you do not do that, as @DTest already said, you will lose that setting on the next mysql restart.

Comment: Updated my answer to do it now on a live site. It would be preferable to implement the cleanup instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know XAMPP that well, but a quick search turned [this](http://www.a3webtech.com/index.php/xampp-3.html) up:

> How to find my.ini and my.cnf
>
> To find these MySQL config files, do this:
>
> 1. Go to Folder Options: in any folder, go to the top horizontal main text menu >> Tools >> Folder Options
> 2. Enable 'View Hidden Files and Folders', and 'View Protected System Files', save & exit
> 3. Go to C Drive, locate and rename the my.ini file, which will now be visible. Rename it as my.ini.bak
> 4. Go to /xampp/msql/bin - locate and rename my.cnf, to my.cnf.bak
> 5. If there is no file my.cnf, but there is one called my - then that is the one you want. Rename it to my.cnf.bak

As for whether you can do this with an online site, you can change it online, but unless you update your my.cnf, the change will be lost after mysql restarts the next time.