# ib_logfile opened with O_SYNC when innodb_flush_method=O_DSYNC

Tags: mysql, innodb

mysql will open and flush data/log files as below when `innodb_flush_method=O_DSYNC`

```
Open log    Flush log   Open datafile   Flush data

O_SYNC       NONE           NONE         fsync ()
```

My First question is ,why do we need to Use `O_SYNC` to open log instead of `O_DSYNC` ?

With `O_DSYNC`, each transaction require one write, but with `O_SYNC` it requires two writes. I think that would make a big difference.

And I found another option in percona server  `ALL_O_DIRECT`: use `O_DIRECT` to open both data and log files, and use fsync() to flush the data files but not the log files.

Tested this option use sysbench OLTP , single thread

response time changes from 20.11ms to 8.3 ms

Test option O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC on mysql 5.7, it still call fsync to flush log files

```
  strace -p `pgrep -x mysqld`  -ff -e trace=desc >strace.out 2>&1 &
  tail -f strace.out |grep "(8\|(9"

  [pid 12258] pwrite(9, "\200\10K\376\2\0\0N\0\0\0L.\0\4\0\2018\0300\2018\2\0\2018\0304\226\240\4\0"..., 1024, 26740736) = 1024
  [pid 12258] fsync(9)                    = 0
  [pid 12258] pwrite(9, "\200\10K\377\2\0\0\25\0\0\0L\10\215\247\3\4\0\0\0\1\247\f\240\37\0\6\0\1\200\4\200"..., 1024, 26741248) = 1024
  [pid 12258] fsync(9)                    = 0
```

Second Question ,beside use ALL_O_DIRECT, any other method could stop innodb from writing metadata of log file into storage device ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this `O_DSYNC` (the option) is fundamentally useless because MySQL/InnoDB engineers saw that it was dangerous in certain cases (corruption), [and disabled it in many cases, making it a synonym to `O_SYNC`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method). it also does an `fsync()` for the same reason.

The main thing you want to tune is `O_DIRECT` vs. default (flushed), and maybe `ALL_O_DIRECT` on Percona.

In your case, I suppose you have good latency to the filesystem (where `O_DIRECT` shines). Sometimes, having the transaction logs on the filesystem cache can be hurtful (although such a difference seem a bit too much for me - did you compare it with `O_DIRECT`, available on all versions of MySQL, which only avoids data file caching?).

Also be careful, because sysbench may not be a good representative of your real-world load. Response times can vary a lot depending on `flush_log_at_trx_commit`, I assume you have that as 1.

According to Dimitri, from Oracle-MySQL, the [solution upstream comes in 5.7](https://twitter.com/dimitrik_fr/status/388303765239246848). I like it for now in Percona, as you can choose.

Comment: flush_log_at_trx_commit is set to 1. I think it's not because my storage have good latency, it's because O_Direct use one write IO when flush a log record, and fsync need two write io, one for writing real datas, another for writing metadata. 

I'm wondering why no one talk about this issue before ? Maybe the reason is 'battery backed write cache',and writing metadata always hint the cache. I'm going to test the option   O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC in mysql 5.7

Comment: Oh no, flushing method/algorithm is #1 talked issue about InnoDB, and that feature has been requested for long. Look at all the real technical posts on mysql performance blog and diaries from InnoDB engineers and others (fb,  etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Please research the kernel of the DB Server as to how journaling is done by the OS. Why? I recently came across a [recent post from mysqlperformanceblog.com](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2014/05/23/improve-innodb-performance-write-bound-loads/) that says the following:

> I also looked at the kernel ext4 sources and changelog. Up to recently, before kernel 3.2, O_DIRECT wasn’t supported with data=journal and MySQL would have issued a warning in the error log. Now, with recent kernels, O_DIRECT is mapped to O_DSYNC and O_DIRECT is faked, always for data=journal, which is exactly what is needed. Indeed, I tried “innodb_flush_method = O_DSYNC” and found the same results. With older kernels I strongly advise to use the “innodb_flush_method = O_DSYNC” setting to make sure files are opened is a way that will cause them to be transactional for ext4. As always, test thoroughfully, I only tested on Ubuntu 14.04.

Did you see that ?

> O_DIRECT is mapped to O_DSYNC and O_DIRECT is faked

Huh? Seriously? That scares me.

## What To Do Next

I have written about [**innodb_flush_method**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method) before ([Clarification on MySQL innodb_flush_method variable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/clarification-on-mysql-innodb-flush-method-variable/1575#1575)). Granted, [innodb_flush_method](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method) set to `O_DIRECT` lets InnoDB take charge of caching. If it is faked, you are at the mercy of the OS. To make matters worse, you are in the cloud. Now, you are really at the mercy of the OS.

Since the OS can be a bottleneck for flushing to disk, I would suggest setting [innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) to something other than 1.

According to the MySQL Documentation on [innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit)

> With a value of 0, any mysqld process crash can erase the last second of transactions. The log buffer is written out to the log file once per second and the flush to disk operation is performed on the log file, but nothing is done at a transaction commit.
>
> With a value of 2, an operating system crash or a power outage can erase the last second of commit records. The log buffer is written out to the file at each commit, but the flush to disk operation is not performed on it. However, the flushing on the log file takes place once per second also when the value is 2. Note that the once-per-second flushing is not 100% guaranteed to happen every second, due to process scheduling issues.

I would go with [innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) set to 0 to get the log buffer flushed.

I would also increase [innodb_log_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size) to 64M or 128M, depending on your write I/O.

Comment: Thanks Roland I read your post (Clarification on MySQL innodb_flush_method variable) already. I know set innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to 2 would hidden the problem, but i want to fix it. Maybe after fix this issue  and combine with the feature of group commit,   innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1 could as good as 2