# Sudden MySQL freeze, with spike in dirty pages, but without obvious write queries

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, buffer-pool, data-pages

I'm systematically (1/2 times per day) experiencing a freeze in the DB server.

Suddenly, all the COMMITs get stuck in 'init' state; they pile up (up to 20/30), an almost no other queries are executed at all.
After ~30 seconds, the server resumes normal operations.

I've mined a lot of data (which follows), which shows that something is going on in InnoDB, but I struggle to find a specific cause.

In the processlist:

- during the problem I see only COMMITs
- before, there are no long-running operations

I've also gone through the binary log, but there is nothing suspicious:

- during the problem, there is nothing being writte
- before, only small queries

As a matter of fact, the binary log starting from shortly before the problem is rather small - being in ROW mode, if there would have been a huge update operation, I would expect it to be large.

I considered a problem with the disk, but the data doesn't fit the pattern of, for example, a sudden disk slowdown.

Which could be the cause? From this type of problem, I would expect a large write query, but I can't find any.

The system is a dedicated server, with 128GB of memory and Dual CPU Intel Xeon E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz.
The storage is a mirror of Seagate 15k disks; the O/S is Ubuntu 14.04, and the files are stored in a separate ext4 partition.

MySQL is v5.6.24, with an allocated buffer pool of 24G.

The query cache is disabled.

Charts, global status and innodb variables follow, with some notes.

In all the charts, each X unit is a second. The problem approximate interval is highlighted by the vertical bars.

Note that I have all the processes, and global status variables, and innodb statuses, archived, for each second of the problem.

## Innodb buffer pool pages

There are significant spikes in the dirty/free pages:

[image: InnoDB dirty/free pages]

And also in the buffer pool size:

[image: InnoDB buffer pool size]

The pages flushed have a very interesting behavior; the don't spike a lot, but InnoDB starts a continuous flushed; after the criticality, it skyrockets:

[image: InnoDB page flushes]

`Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free` is always 0.

## Log file

The is an increase in the data written to the log file, although not huge:

[image: Log file writes]

## Disk operations

There are no significant change in pending operations (fsyncs/read/writes), but is a drop in the actual fsyncs:

[image: Innodb fsyncs]

## Commands

Almost all the commands (Com_*) don't execute during the problem.
The following are the only ones executing, which clearly plunged:

[image: Selects]
[image: Commits]
[image: Inserts]
[image: Updates]

## Current global status (partial)

`+-----------------------------------------------+----------------+
| Aborted_clients                               | 4767955        |
| Aborted_connects                              | 33             |
| Binlog_cache_disk_use                         | 47747          |
| Binlog_cache_use                              | 68002226       |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use                    | 0              |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_use                         | 682187         |
| Bytes_received                                | 810930341088   |
| Bytes_sent                                    | 6128156018408  |
| Com_admin_commands                            | 66190088       |
| Com_alter_table                               | 5837           |
| Com_analyze                                   | 9742           |
| Com_begin                                     | 328167299      |
| Com_change_db                                 | 216            |
| Com_commit                                    | 327839739      |
| Com_create_db                                 | 13             |
| Com_create_index                              | 1              |
| Com_create_table                              | 877609         |
| Com_delete                                    | 13720394       |
| Com_delete_multi                              | 89347          |
| Com_drop_db                                   | 14             |
| Com_drop_table                                | 740674         |
| Com_insert                                    | 130474570      |
| Com_insert_select                             | 572148         |
| Com_kill                                      | 98             |
| Com_load                                      | 1              |
| Com_lock_tables                               | 3              |
| Com_release_savepoint                         | 28061          |
| Com_rename_table                              | 978            |
| Com_replace                                   | 7995547        |
| Com_replace_select                            | 46493          |
| Com_rollback                                  | 284617         |
| Com_rollback_to_savepoint                     | 3              |
| Com_savepoint                                 | 28062          |
| Com_select                                    | 1664064423     |
| Com_set_option                                | 152369114      |
| Com_show_create_table                         | 64205947       |
| Com_show_databases                            | 11             |
| Com_show_engine_status                        | 1375041        |
| Com_show_fields                               | 97123409       |
| Com_show_keys                                 | 1              |
| Com_show_master_status                        | 66             |
| Com_show_processlist                          | 2624788        |
| Com_show_slave_status                         | 1250533        |
| Com_show_status                               | 1591300        |
| Com_show_table_status                         | 198            |
| Com_show_tables                               | 90403059       |
| Com_show_triggers                             | 197            |
| Com_show_variables                            | 1580763        |
| Com_show_warnings                             | 3              |
| Com_unlock_tables                             | 4              |
| Com_update                                    | 39673285       |
| Com_update_multi                              | 1259352        |
| Compression                                   | OFF            |
| Connections                                   | 5426115        |
| Created_tmp_disk_tables                       | 108340111      |
| Created_tmp_files                             | 633100         |
| Created_tmp_tables                            | 350818717      |
| Delayed_errors                                | 0              |
| Delayed_insert_threads                        | 0              |
| Delayed_writes                                | 0              |
| Flush_commands                                | 1              |
| Handler_commit                                | 2607344684     |
| Handler_delete                                | 59374751       |
| Handler_discover                              | 0              |
| Handler_external_lock                         | 6579792721     |
| Handler_mrr_init                              | 0              |
| Handler_prepare                               | 379741472      |
| Handler_read_first                            | 122813781      |
| Handler_read_key                              | 300828885004   |
| Handler_read_last                             | 68546          |
| Handler_read_next                             | 1973974492391  |
| Handler_read_prev                             | 535277275      |
| Handler_read_rnd                              | 25166576467    |
| Handler_read_rnd_next                         | 403233196007   |
| Handler_rollback                              | 7441860        |
| Handler_savepoint                             | 56123          |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback                    | 4              |
| Handler_update                                | 7089849963     |
| Handler_write                                 | 45088211806    |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status                | not started    |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status                | not started    |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data                 | 1376429        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data                 | 22551412736    |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty                | 54             |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty                | 884736         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed              | 511407857      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free                 | 8196           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc                 | 188235         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total                | 1572860        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd             | 0              |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead                 | 43857258       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted         | 1057           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests              | 3228343017942  |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads                      | 244620532      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free                  | 0              |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests             | 89857610256    |
| Innodb_data_fsyncs                            | 252778445      |
| Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs                    | 0              |
| Innodb_data_pending_reads                     | 0              |
| Innodb_data_pending_writes                    | 0              |
| Innodb_data_read                              | 4856234004480  |
| Innodb_data_reads                             | 300490939      |
| Innodb_data_writes                            | 688782200      |
| Innodb_data_written                           | 20083187664896 |
| Innodb_dblwr_pages_written                    | 511407857      |
| Innodb_dblwr_writes                           | 80028802       |
| Innodb_have_atomic_builtins                   | ON             |
| Innodb_log_waits                              | 83             |
| Innodb_log_write_requests                     | 6576724198     |
| Innodb_log_writes                             | 91699110       |
| Innodb_os_log_fsyncs                          | 92727019       |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs                  | 0              |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_writes                  | 0              |
| Innodb_os_log_written                         | 3324697918464  |
| Innodb_page_size                              | 16384          |
| Innodb_pages_created                          | 131874643      |
| Innodb_pages_read                             | 296401190      |
| Innodb_pages_written                          | 511407857      |
| Innodb_row_lock_current_waits                 | 5              |
| Innodb_row_lock_time                          | 193034202      |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_avg                      | 607            |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max                      | 121631         |
| Innodb_row_lock_waits                         | 317570         |
| Innodb_rows_deleted                           | 59374751       |
| Innodb_rows_inserted                          | 16430811966    |
| Innodb_rows_read                              | 2466321863882  |
| Innodb_rows_updated                           | 108284843      |
| Innodb_num_open_files                         | 4              |
| Innodb_truncated_status_writes                | 0              |
| Innodb_available_undo_logs                    | 128            |
| Key_blocks_not_flushed                        | 0              |
| Key_blocks_unused                             | 857368         |
| Key_blocks_used                               | 6054           |
| Key_read_requests                             | 2074128816     |
| Key_reads                                     | 0              |
| Key_write_requests                            | 292337091      |
| Key_writes                                    | 0              |
| Last_query_cost                               | 0.000000       |
| Last_query_partial_plans                      | 0              |
| Max_used_connections                          | 157            |
| Not_flushed_delayed_rows                      | 0              |
| Open_files                                    | 24             |
| Open_streams                                  | 0              |
| Open_table_definitions                        | 352            |
| Open_tables                                   | 528            |
| Opened_files                                  | 437024702      |
| Opened_table_definitions                      | 1775335        |
| Opened_tables                                 | 914419         |
| Prepared_stmt_count                           | 0              |
| Queries                                       | 4907804173     |
| Questions                                     | 4841613101     |
| Select_full_join                              | 46349          |
| Select_full_range_join                        | 82799          |
| Select_range                                  | 266986250      |
| Select_range_check                            | 536            |
| Select_scan                                   | 304460971      |
| Slow_launch_threads                           | 0              |
| Slow_queries                                  | 144689         |
| Sort_merge_passes                             | 3055697        |
| Sort_range                                    | 119144232      |
| Sort_rows                                     | 30616561566    |
| Sort_scan                                     | 115294967      |
| Table_locks_immediate                         | 3285742243     |
| Table_locks_waited                            | 0              |
| Table_open_cache_hits                         | 3445246883     |
| Table_open_cache_misses                       | 169145         |
| Table_open_cache_overflows                    | 0              |
| Threads_cached                                | 43             |
| Threads_connected                             | 64             |
| Threads_created                               | 278            |
| Threads_running                               | 2              |
| Uptime                                        | 8670805        |
| Uptime_since_flush_status                     | 8670805        |
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------+`

## Innodb variables

`+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                            | Value                  |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| innodb_adaptive_flushing                 | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm             | 10                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index               | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay          | 150000                 |
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size          | 8388608                |
| innodb_api_bk_commit_interval            | 5                      |
| innodb_api_disable_rowlock               | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_mdl                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_trx_level                     | 0                      |
| innodb_autoextend_increment              | 64                     |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                 | 1                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown      | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now              | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename              | <removed>              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances             | 8                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort            | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup       | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now              | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                  | 25769803776            |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size            | 25                     |
| innodb_change_buffering                  | all                    |
| innodb_checksum_algorithm                | innodb                 |
| innodb_checksums                         | ON                     |
| innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled             | OFF                    |
| innodb_commit_concurrency                | 0                      |
| innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct | 5                      |
| innodb_compression_level                 | 6                      |
| innodb_compression_pad_pct_max           | 50                     |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets               | 5000                   |
| innodb_data_file_path                    | ibdata1:12M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir                     | <removed>              |
| innodb_disable_sort_file_cache           | OFF                    |
| innodb_doublewrite                       | ON                     |
| innodb_fast_shutdown                     | 1                      |
| innodb_file_format                       | Antelope               |
| innodb_file_format_check                 | ON                     |
| innodb_file_format_max                   | Antelope               |
| innodb_file_per_table                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout              | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit           | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_method                      | O_DIRECT               |
| innodb_flush_neighbors                   | 1                      |
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops                | 30                     |
| innodb_force_load_corrupted              | OFF                    |
| innodb_force_recovery                    | 0                      |
| innodb_ft_aux_table                      |                        |
| innodb_ft_cache_size                     | 8000000                |
| innodb_ft_enable_diag_print              | OFF                    |
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword                | ON                     |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                 | 84                     |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                 | 3                      |
| innodb_ft_num_word_optimize              | 2000                   |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit             | 2000000000             |
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table          |                        |
| innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree                | 2                      |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size               | 640000000              |
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table            |                        |
| innodb_io_capacity                       | 200                    |
| innodb_io_capacity_max                   | 2000                   |
| innodb_large_prefix                      | OFF                    |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                 | 120                    |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog           | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                   | 8388608                |
| innodb_log_compressed_pages              | ON                     |
| innodb_log_file_size                     | 134217728              |
| innodb_log_files_in_group                | 3                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir                | <removed>              |
| innodb_lru_scan_depth                    | 1024                   |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct               | 75                     |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm           | 0                      |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                     | 0                      |
| innodb_max_purge_lag_delay               | 0                      |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups               | 1                      |
| innodb_monitor_disable                   |                        |
| innodb_monitor_enable                    |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset                     |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset_all                 |                        |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct                    | 37                     |
| innodb_old_blocks_time                   | 1000                   |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size         | 134217728              |
| innodb_open_files                        | 300                    |
| innodb_optimize_fulltext_only            | OFF                    |
| innodb_page_size                         | 16384                  |
| innodb_print_all_deadlocks               | OFF                    |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                  | 300                    |
| innodb_purge_threads                     | 1                      |
| innodb_random_read_ahead                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold              | 56                     |
| innodb_read_io_threads                   | 4                      |
| innodb_read_only                         | OFF                    |
| innodb_replication_delay                 | 0                      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout               | OFF                    |
| innodb_rollback_segments                 | 128                    |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size                  | 1048576                |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay                   | 6                      |
| innodb_stats_auto_recalc                 | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_method                      | nulls_equal            |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_persistent                  | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages     | 20                     |
| innodb_stats_sample_pages                | 8                      |
| innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages      | 8                      |
| innodb_status_output                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_status_output_locks               | OFF                    |
| innodb_strict_mode                       | OFF                    |
| innodb_support_xa                        | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_array_size                   | 1                      |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                   | 30                     |
| innodb_table_locks                       | ON                     |
| innodb_thread_concurrency                | 0                      |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay                | 10000                  |
| innodb_undo_directory                    | .                      |
| innodb_undo_logs                         | 128                    |
| innodb_undo_tablespaces                  | 0                      |
| innodb_use_native_aio                    | ON                     |
| innodb_use_sys_malloc                    | ON                     |
| innodb_version                           | 5.6.24                 |
| innodb_write_io_threads                  | 4                      |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+`

Comment: What is the server OS and the filesystem type(s) where MySQL files are?

Comment: added! ubuntu 14.04. data on a separate ext4 partition.

Comment: Please post output of `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';`

Comment: I'd look at the OS level what user or system processes might be hogging the disk at the time this happens. I've seen anti-virus software, search indexing, and btrfs snapshots causing similar symptoms.

Comment: If that would be the case, wouldn't there be spikes in the innodb_data variables? Also, I can't relate it to the spike in dirty pages.

Comment: Do you use some form of replication? Are there some DDL (alter etc) statements running?

Comment: Yes, I do use replication, but this is the master, and based on the data I see, I suspect something related to writing is happening (although, I'm certainly not sure). Definitely no DDLs or any long running queries.

Comment: You wrote about binlog starting just before so it probably is not binlog rotation.. Maybe slave is not receiving old binlog fast enough? (No real idea..)

Comment: You said `The system has 128GB of memory, with an allocated buffer pool of 112GB. MySQL is v5.6.24.` but your buffer pool is only 24G. Is this a dedicated MySQL server or is there a full stack in the server (Nagios, Munin, Tomcat, Apache, PHP, things like these) ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: I think the 24<>112 a misconfiguration (a mismatch of the configuration file vs the live setting). The server is dedicated (dual CPU Intel Xeon E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long experimentation, I've found the problem to be the infamous swap insanity.

The problem has been fixed by using the `innodb-numa-interleave` option.

Comment: Were you seeing any actual writes to swap during this or just the data volume?

Comment: I can't remember, sorry! I just know that once I've set that option, the problem went away.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to tune your writes for InnoDB and possibly your ext4 volume

## ASPECT #1

I noticed you have [**innodb_write_io_threads**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) set to 4 (default value). You need to increase that so dirty pages can get flushed to their respective `.ibd` files more robustly. Please set it 16.

## ASPECT #2

That pause to perform write might be do to ext4. Why ?

You have [innodb_flush_method](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method) set to `O_DIRECT`. This is supposed to make disk writes more stable. Nevertheless, I a surprise for you. I answered [ib_logfile opened with O_SYNC when innodb_flush_method=O_DSYNC](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72721/ib-logfile-opened-with-o-sync-when-innodb-flush-method-o-dsync/72744#72744) about a year ago. I mentioned a [*Percona blog that says that **O_DIRECT is faked in ext4 with the latest kernel***](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/05/23/improve-innodb-performance-write-bound-loads/).

1. You need to make sure you have the latest Linux kernel (3.2 or greater)
2. Change [innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) to 0

Comment: Wow! Will try and let you know; in the meanwhile, thanks!

Comment: Should the number of io_threads match the number of .ibd files you have for maximum performance?

Comment: @Freedo Read and Write IO threads only go to a maximum of 64. It's not practical to raise it based on the number of InnoDB tables. See my other post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/about-single-threaded-versus-multithreaded-databases-performance/2948#2948 for more info